# Mysql Haversine Procedure (radius)using a center point 

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm fairly new to MySql and what I want is to create a procedure where i can just plug in any zipcode and a distance and get back all the zipcodes within that distance.  I did find a formula and tried to reshape it for what I need but I'm unable to do it.  What I have is below.  The example is from here http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html.  However, i don't want to use 37, -122 coordinates, i want to use whichever zipcode I push into the procedure.  I'd start a bounty if i could but I'd have to wait.  This one has stumped me all day so any help is appreciated. This one has stumped me because i believe it uses two sets of lat/lon and i only want a radius from a central lat/lon

```
SELECT state,city,zipcode,
   (3959
    * acos(
           cos(radians(37))
         * cos(radians(x(location)))
         * cos(radians(y(location)) - radians(-122))
         + sin(radians(37)) * sin(radians(x(location)))))
      AS distance
  FROM zipcodes
HAVING distance < 25
 ORDER BY distance
 LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this the same way you approach collision-detection style algorithms. Check if the coordinates are inside a bounding box by finding the minimum and maximum lat/long (given the radius) from a point, and make sure that the search meets some fast to evaluate criteria (e.g. `lat <= 1.5`) before running more resource intensive checks.

There is a working example with SQL and Java code here:

http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates

In summary, it says the following:

> Simply combining the conditions with
>   AND:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM Places WHERE
>     (Lat => 1.2393 AND Lat <= 1.5532) AND (Lon >= -1.8184 AND Lon <= 0.4221)
> AND
>     acos(sin(1.3963) * sin(Lat) + cos(1.3963) * cos(Lat) * cos(Lon -
> ```
>
> (-0.6981))) <=         0.1570;
>
> Most query optimizers are smart enough
>   to perform an index scan to quickly
>   find places satisfying (Lat >= 1.2393

It then goes on to perform some additional checks. There are some alternative approaches along the same theme underneath this.

Does this help you? It looks like you have the skill to write this into a procedure yourself, but if you like I can try and write one for you. If so can you paste/post your table or an SQL batch script.

Comment: I may have missed the point of your question too. Are you just trying to use your existing procedure search using only a zip code? If this is the case, see my above comment about posting your table.