# google maps radius search

Tags: mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a database of hotels with address, also POI's with latitude and longitude.

I would like to search these POI's around the hotel with radius (5km 10 km...). How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radius/nearest results - Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755905/radius-nearest-results-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 2):

There is a (fairly extensive) tutorial for creating a "Store Locator" type page in JavaScript, MySQL PHP available from the Google Geo APIs Team here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

If you see the section under "Searching near a geocode", you could modify this to be a set geo-code for the hotel. Alternately you could just provide it with a string for the name of the hotel. This really depends on how you want your search to function.

Does this help you?

P.S. I also posted here about creating a super-efficient version of this if you want to optimize your own version [Mysql Haversine Procedure (radius)using a center point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352089/mysql-haversine-procedure-radiususing-a-center-point/6354767#6354767)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
*,
ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `lat` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $lat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `lat` ) )
* COS( RADIANS( $lat )) * COS( RADIANS( `lon` ) - RADIANS( $long )) ) * 6380 AS `distance`
FROM `places`
WHERE
ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `lat` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $lat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `lat` ) )
* COS( RADIANS( $lat )) * COS( RADIANS( `lon` ) - RADIANS( $long )) ) * 6380 < 10
ORDER BY `distance`
```

10 is radius in km
`$lat` and `$long` is the center or the circle
`lat` and `lon` are attributes if your table